# Suppress UCM default head scripts from generated webpages

Tags: oracle-ucm, idocscript

By default UCM adds a bunch of JavaScript to the head of each webpage. Is there a way to suppress the insertion of these scripts at the page level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a resolution to the issue. It is Site Studio Designer that automatically inserts scripts into the head of documents you work with. The solution is to write your .hcsp source in another editor (I use Notepad++), then manually check your code into UCM.